# Attempting to display image using pixel values in OpenCV. Only 1/3rd of Image shows

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm attempting to read the pixels in an image and convert them into another format by iterating through the pixels.

After my conversion I only seem to be getting 1/3rd of the image and I'm certain it's because of the way I'm accessing the pixels using the .at() function.

I'm reading in the following image:

[image: camera man image]

```
Mat image = imread("cameraman.jpg");
```

I then iterate through the images rows and columns:

```
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++)
   {
      placeGrayValue((double)image.at<uchar>(i, j));
   }
}
```

Note: `placedGrayValue()` is just a placeholder here so that I can share only the code that is relevant.

The resulting image is only the first third of the image:

[image: cropped camera man image with only first 1/3rd vertical strip showing]

Comment: What is `flipped`? What is `placeGrayValue`? Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: imread("cameraman.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

Comment: I updated the post. I was trying to remove irrelevant code to keep things as succinct as possible.

Comment: Height and width correct way round? Pixels definitely planar and not interleaved? That's the usual suspects but without more info on placeGrayValue, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading your image with `cv::imread`, which with default value (`cv::IMREAD_COLOR`) will load it as a 3 channel image of type `CV_8UC3` (aka `cv::Mat3b`).

If your original image is grayscale, when loading as a 3 channel image you have the same intensity value for each channel.

So when you scan the image you should access pixels with `.at<cv::Vec3b>(...)`.
If you want to copy only the first channel to the `placeGrayValue` matrix you should do it as:

```
placeGrayValue((double)image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[0]);
                                ^^^^^^^^^       ^^^
                                3 channel       first channel
```

If your input is not a grayscale image, then you shouldn't just copy the first channel, since the grayscale value is a linear combination of the three R,G,B channels.
So it's better to first convert to grayscale, and then copy:

```
cv::Mat grayscale;
cv::cvtColor(image, grayscale, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
...
    placeGrayValue((double)grayscale.at<uchar>(i, j));
                                        ^^^^^
                                       1 channel
```

Or you can load the image already as a grayscale image:

```
Mat grayscale = imread("cameraman.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

At the end, you want to have `placeGrayValue` with the grayscale values as `double`.
You should not scan the image for this kind of easy operations. You can just:

```
cv::Mat placeGrayValue;
grayscale.convertTo(placeGrayValue, CV_64F);
                                    ^^^^^^ 
                                   to double type
```

Summing up:

```
cv::Mat grayscale = cv::imread("cameraman.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
cv::Mat placeGrayValue;
grayscale.convertTo(placeGrayValue, CV_64F);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll post what ended up working as an answer, though it makes little sense to me and I'd still like to understand why.

The image has 3 channels. When iterate through an image using a for loop and extract pixel data with `(double)image.at<uchar>(i, j)` it goes through each channel as if they were individual pixels.

The solution (at least with this grayscale image) is to iterate and multiply by 3. In other words, `(double)image.at<uchar>(i*3, j)` ended up giving me the full image.